# Is it possible to override one Yarn resolution with another?

Tags: npm, dependencies, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Is there some sort of rule of specificity like CSS for example? Is it possible to use resolutions for your entire project *except* one dependency?

I've tried code like this (with and without `nohoist`) but I never have luck getting the correct dependency resolutions.

```js
"resolutions": {
  "react": "18.0.0",
  "**/mobile-app/react": "^17.0.2",
  "**/mobile-app/**/react": "^17.0.2"
}
```